# Java - arraylist of multidimensional arrays or arraylist of multidimensional arraylists?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I'm learning Java and am trying to wrap my head around these data structures. I'm coming from Python/PHP so I'm used to dynamically sizing arrays on the fly and being able to store multiple data types in one array.

How would I best store this data? Say I don't know how many rows I'll have, but I do know that each row will hold 2 columns of data. One column being a string, and the other column being a double.

Example in pseudo-ish code if I had 3 rows:

```
array(array("description1", 10.00),
      array("description2", 12.00),
      array("description3", 14.00));
```

Then, I want to loop through the array to process the datawith something like:

```
foreach(rows as row){
    myStringVal = row[0]; //on first iteration would be "description1"
    myIntVal = row[1];    //on first iteration would be 10.00
    ... do something with the values ...
}
```

I'm thinking I need to create an arraylist that holds an array, but I can't store both strings and doubles in a java array, so what do i do? Do I use a map instead, and treat it as if it were an array? For example, do I create a map where the first element is a numeric ID for each row, the second element is the string value, the 3rd element is the double value, and then I use a loop to increase a counter and grab each row from the map that using the numeric ID>

Really confused as to how this will work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not storing "different kind of values", you're storing semantic data that encodes "a tuple" but using the non-java concept of just sticking that in an array. Don't do that, instead use the C/C++/Java concept of encoding linked data as a struct/object:

```
// our "struct"esque class for the linked data we're handling
class MyObject {
  String description;
  float value;
  Public MyObject(String description, float value) {
    this.description = description;
    this.value = value;
  }
}

// build our list of objects
ArrayList<MyObject> mylist = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
mylist.add(new MyObject("description1", 10));
mylist.add(new MyObject("description2", 12));
mylist.add(new MyObject("description3", 14));
...

// and then we iterate
String d; float v;
for(MyObject m: mylist) {
  d = m.description;
  v = m.value;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Nice, really like this answer too. Makes total sense. Wish I could give two answers.

Comment: +1 "Proper" Java style would be to also implement `equals() and hashcode()` and perhaps toString().

Comment: Not for a struct object. equals and hashcode are only required if you intend to do matching/hashing, which we're not doing in this case (they are inherited from Object by default)

Answer (score 2):

It *looks* like a `List<Map<String, BigDecimal>>` to me.

- The `List` will give you the ability to enter more than one element continuously.
- The `Map` will give you the association between the `String` and floating-point value, which I've chosen `BigDecimal` to represent.  You could use `Double` if you wanted.

  ```
  List<Map<String, BigDecimal>> elements = new ArrayList<>();
  elements.add(new HashMap<String, BigDecimal>());
  elements.get(0).put("description1", BigDecimal.valueOf("10.00"));
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to choose this as the answer, but I like Mike 'Pomax' Kamerman's answer too... it's probably the better way to do this, but I'm just looking for the quick/dirty way for now. Wish I could give two answers the check mark.

Comment: to be fair, you could do this, but it's note quite the Java way, where the proper OOP approach is to encode anything that represents "a thing" as an object. Given the question, it sounds like a decent solution, but given the intended program behaviour, it's kind of not  =)

Comment: @Mike Yeah, I definitely agree. What kinda sucks is that I have to follow along with the class I'm in, and it requires doing stuff the "wrong" way, but it forces us to learn the data structures pretty well.  I've lost points in the past for using techniques that weren't taught in class yet, so I'm going to stick with this idea for now.

Comment: just remember that S.O. is not about your homework, but about getting the right answers to questions. If you flag a 'wrong' answer is the right one because your class is teaching things wrong, be aware that future SO visitors might use this thread to guide their programming. You're not just accepting an answer for yourself, you're also steering the education of future visitors =)

Comment: True, flipped it. Thanks guys, very helpful.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: I would argue that this isn't teaching them how to do the "wrong" thing.  Yes, using an object would be *better*, but this is still a valid approach.  It depends on how the data needs to be accessed, as to what inner data structure you use within the List.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class instead of an array.

```
public class X
{
    private final String description;
    private final double value;

    public X(final String desc,
             final double val)
    {
        decription = desc;
        value      = val;
    }

    // getters
}
```

If you want to be able to change the description and value then don't make them final.

You could make the `description` and `value` variables public, but I would avoid that temptation.